# share memory between dll in the same process

Tags: c++, memory, dll, share

I have a class named CMemCfg which is a singleton, the CMemCfg class has a lot of data members which storage configuration data . If I put CMemCfg in server.exe, then other dlls should uesd callback function to visit function(get data from data members) in CMemCfg . So I want to put the CMemCfg class(also a singleton) in a dll, but that will cause another problem, every function of CMemCfg should have an export function which lead to duplication of code. 
Should I just export CMemCfg(singleton) class?
Is there another solution to share memory between dll in the same process?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider initializing other dlls with instance of CMemCfg. No callbacks, no duplicating exports, the only change is modified (added) initialization function.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should stick with exporting the class from the DLL. To export a class from a dll you only need to declare that you are exporting the class, and not each member variable. You can use dll main to create the singleton instance, and export a function along the lines of "`GetSingletonObject()`" to allow clients to use your object.

You could use shared memory section to share memory, but I think this will be more work than just exporting the singleton.